# Why is "der" used in the following sentence?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-structure

I came across this sentence in a podcast transcription:

> Wer bald in den Urlaub fährt, der bucht gerne sein Hotel oder den Flug im Internet.

and I think, without "der", the sentence would still hold, with the "wer..." part functioning as a subject clause followed directly by the main-clause verb, so why did "der" show up here?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a more economic speaker could omit the "der" and concatenate the two partial clauses into a single sentence without changing the meaning. But the verb "fahren" holds its place, it will not change to the front after the "Wer". E.g.:

> Wer bald in den Urlaub fährt, bucht gerne sein Hotel oder den Flug online.

Grammar "Relativsätze": https://deutschegrammatik20.de/attribute/relativsatz/relativsaetze-wer-wen-wem-wessen/

Doesn't a similar thing exist in English language ? "She/he/those who travel soon (, they) frequently book online" ? Does it sound unusual ?

The construct is frequently connected with sayings:

> Wer im Glashaus sitzt, (der) sollte nicht mit Steinen werfen

is not a relative clause in English:

> If you sit in a glass house don't throw stones

Otoh, the relative clause (Relativsatz) can even stand alone (in both languages) when it's clear e.g. from cultural reference what is meant:

> Wem die Stunde schlägt

is

> For whom the bell tolls (it tolls for thee :-))

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. I also want to know what is the grammar behind "der" here? What is its role or function, please?

Comment: Sure: the first part is a "Relativsatz" with an undefined relative pronoun ("Wer", "Wen", "Wem", "Was"). It can be omitted in the main clause (after the comma) because it is clear who is meant.

Comment: @RHa danke für die Korrektur. Wenn mich nicht alles täuscht sollte das Komma aber nur da sein wenn "der" folgt, sonst nicht. Sehe ich das richtig ? Ich hab's nicht so mit der Zeichensetzung, gebe ich unumwunden zu ...

Comment: Es handelt sich in beiden Fällen um einen Nebensatz, und die Regel lautet: *Steht der Nebensatz vor oder nach dem Hauptsatz, werden die Teilsätze durch ein Komma getrennt*. Das gilt unabhängig davon, ob ein *der* verwendet wird.

Comment: Gracias. Dafür kann ich mehrere Sprachen :-)